# Python3 pathlib adding extra backslashes \\

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just learnt about pathlib which supposedly should make file paths and locations operating system agnostic.
However when using write file function the pathlib is adding an extra backslash in windows "\" (havent tested in POSIX based os) , here is code

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("subDir/myFile")
print("file to write to is>>", path)
with path.open(mode='a') as outputlog:
    outputlog.write('foo')
```

It gives the following output

> file to write to is>> subDir\myFile
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'subDir\\myFile'

Comment: `Path("subDir/myFile)` is a syntax error. Do you have a current directory issue BTW?

Comment: The extra backslash isn't the problem, that's just python escaping. `repr(r'dir\file') == "'dir\\file'"`. I think your path doesn't exist -- do you have a spelling error. What's the result of `os.path.exists(str(path))`?

Comment: Yes you are right the dir was missing solved it by creating the directories using 
     self.path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for the suggestions the parent directories were indeed missing this fixed by first creating the path of directories only (without filename) and then

```
self.path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```